# Normal Form - 4th Normal Form

Tags: database-design, database-normalization, third-normal-form

I have this data that I need to put into 3rd and 4th Normal Form.

I understand the basics of normal form but I'm confused with 3rd and 4th normal form and I've checked online but still don't understand.

I'm creating a database which is being used by my system.

[image: Data]

Comment: You can't tell how to put something into 3NF (or 4NF, for that matter) based on a snippet of data; they are based on the relationships between the attributes, which you have not explained.

Comment: The basic idea behind 3NF is to avoid redundancy; so, for example, if certain fields are based only the user (like name, email & mailing addresses), but not a particular booking, you can avoid redundancies in customer info by having a table just about customers, and a separate table with bookings that refers to the customer table (typically w/ a customer id).

Comment: Between those NFs is the important BCNF. Has this not been mentioned? Maybe this is what you actually need rather than 3NF? Being in 4NF implies being in BCNF and 3NF. What exactly is your task?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

A relation in 4NF is also in BCNF, 3NF and the lower NFs.

From  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24980837/3404097):

> A superkey is a set of columns that uniquely identifies rows.
>
> A candidate key is a set of columns that uniquely identifies rows and
> that contains no smaller ("proper") subset of columns that uniquely
> identifies rows.
>
> So a
> candidate key is a superkey that contains no smaller superkey.

A [multi-valued dependecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_dependency) (MVD) X ->> Y holds in a table (ie a table has that MVD) with attribute set R when the table can be expressed as the join of the two tables that are its projections on attribute sets X U Y and X U (R - Y). (Because an MVD is a binary [join dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_dependency) (JD)).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_normal_form):

> A trivial multivalued dependency X ->> Y is one where
> either Y is a subset of X, or X and Y together form the whole set of
> attributes of the relation.
>
> A Table is in 4NF if and only if, for every one of its non-trivial
> multivalued dependencies X ->> Y, X is a superkey—that
> is, X is either a candidate key or a superset thereof.

Every table has a *predicate*, ie a statement template parameterized by the table's attribute names, where the rows that go in the table are the ones that make a true statement by replacing attribute names in the predicate by the corresponding attribute values in the row. The MVD X ->> Y holds in a table when its predicate *P* can be rephrased as:
        
FOR SOME values for the attributes not in X U Y, *P*
    
AND FOR SOME values for the attributes not in X U (R - Y), *P*

So let your table's meaning be your guide to CKs, superkeys and MVDs. To normalize from BCNF to 4NF: If a non-trivial MVD X ->> Y not out of a superkey holds then replace the table by its projections on X U Y and X U (R - Y); repeat on the new tables.